# How to iterate two lists into dict using __next__ python

Tags: python, loops

```
class Checkout():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__items = []
        self.__amounts = []  # The number of each item
        self.__person_name = name

    def __iter__(self):
        self.iterIndex = -1
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        pass
```

How would I go about using the _ *next* _ function to iterate through both lists and return them into a dictionary with a size 2 containing the key/value of item and amount

Comment: Could your provide an example of what you mean? Do you want `next(Checkout())` to return something like `{'item': "foo", 'amount': 1}`?

Comment: You might want to consider something like `yield from (dict(item=x, amount=y) for x,y in zip(self.__items, self.__amounts))` and skip defining `__next__` explicitly. This has the benefit of allowing multiple independent iterators for each instance of `Checkout`.

Comment: Also, does items and amounts has the same length? It looks like you should be sure of that

Comment: And is there a reason for storing items and their amounts separately, rather than (say) a single list of tuples that keep each item explicitly paid with its amount?

Comment: @chepner can you post a solution, I am curious to see that yield alternative for independent iterators =)

Comment: @chepner exactly, but more like {"foo":1.00} also I am required by the specifications to use two separate lists to better understand how to use __next__ to iterate through them and put them in a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could solve your problem. But maybe you can go with only one list of tuples.

```
class Checkout():                                                        
    def __init__(self):                                                  
        self._items = [1,2,3]                                            
        self._amounts = [4,5,6]  # The number of each item               
                                                                         
    def __iter__(self):                                                  
        self.iterIndex = 0                                               
        return self                                                      
                                                                         
    def __next__(self):                                                  
        if self.iterIndex >= len(self._items):                           
            raise StopIteration                                          
        else:                                                            
            values = list(zip(self._items,self._amounts))[self.iterIndex]
            self.iterIndex += 1                                          
            return {"items": values[0], "amount": values[1]}             
                                                                         
                                                                         
a = Checkout()                                                           
i = iter(a)                                                              
print(next(i))                                                           
print(next(i))                                                           
print(next(i))                                                           
print(next(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

`__iter__` just has to return *an* iterator, not necessarily the object to serve as its own iterator. One possibility is to return a `generator` that yields the desired `dict`s.

```
class Checkout:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__items = []
        self.__amounts = []
        self.__person_name = name

    def __iter__(self):
        for item, amount in zip(self.__items, self.__amounts):
            yield {item: amount}
```